# Trying to acess data of an object, says inaccessible

Tags: php, laravel, object

i am trying to access property of object but while it shows the data is object but when i try to access the property it gives error 'Use of undefined constant 'id';
the code is ;

```
function returnProducts(Request $request,$id){
    $user = Auth::user();
    if($user->hasRole(['customer','bos_customer','admin','vendor','business_owner',
        'merchant','city_manager','city_order_manager'])){
        $sale = Sale::find($id);
        $saleDetail=$sale->saleDetails;
        $num=count($saleDetail);         
      return $request->product_ids[id];
```

[image]

the input recieved from the front-end is called from

```
return $request;
```

[image]

how can i access the object property i tried accesing it but cannot wrap my head around the problem  i am facing

Comment: `return $request->product_ids[id]` should be `return $request->product_ids[$id]` (You missed a `$` before `id`)

Comment: yeah i can see that working, i was so happy finally to see a working way, but unfortunately it will not work . it yields error: undefined offset:6

Comment: You'll have to debug what `$request->product_ids` contains, then use the correct `index`. If `[$id]` is incorrect (undefined), then you'll need to figure out how to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

problem probably is here:

change this:

```
return $request->product_ids[id];
```

to:

```
return $request->product_ids['id'];
```

or:

```
 return $request->product_ids[$id];
```

Comment: while using,return $request->product_ids[$id] it will give me error 500 undefined offset 6 and while using return $requset->product[id] it will give me error ,"use of undefined constant id -assumed id,this will throw error in future php.
and, when i use return $request->product_ids['id'] it will give me error of use of undefined index:id.